# Rotate the boot screen animation

Tags: boot, rotate

Is it possible to set screen rotation for ubuntu boot animation? (The one with ubuntu logo and dots)

Comment: Can you specify your actual requirement.. What is your screen resolution? After boot animation you want to use your screen as portrait or landscape? What version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 on gpd pocket2 fullhd resolution

Comment: I tried yesterday to today.. But could not break the code for those flashing dots.. But it is possible to rotate the Ubuntu logo with easy steps..